# Assistance with an gibberish translator

Tags: c++, qt, if-statement

Ok so with extensive help from a fellow stackoverflow man I came up with a program (mostly him) that encrypts english. This is using Qt. But right now it only makes it upper or lower case. this is the part of the code I need to modify.

```
    void translationForm::translate()
    {
        if(mode_comboBox->currentText() == "Encrypt")
        {
            QString str = lhs->toPlainText();
            rhs->setText(str.toUpper());
        }
        else
        {
            QString str = lhs->toPlainText();
            rhs->setText(str.toLower());
        }
    }
```

So pretty simple. And my question might be simple I just can't figure it out.

This used to be a console program. And this is the code I used to encrypt it.

```
    int index=0;
    while(str[index])
    {
        str[index]=(str[index]+1)%256;
        index++;
    }
    std::cout << str;
```

But for some reason that does not work if I put it in. So what am I doing wrong? I pasted it after the toPlainText(); line and then replaced the setText to just str. How can I fix this?

EDIT(Adding Decryption Code):

```
else {
    int index=0;
    while(str[index++]) {}
        for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
        {
            str[i]-=1;
            if(str[i]==-1)
            {
                str[i]=255;
            }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your second code block is a function std::cout echoes to the console, so you won't see your results returned from the function.  Try return str; instead of std:cout << str;

Comment: The only part that matters here is the index variable and the while loop how can I set QString str as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, `str` in second block of text is not `QString`. I recommend you using `Qt`'s types when writing in `Qt` - they are very easy to use.

Working block of code:

```
QByteArray encrypt(const QByteArray &str)
{
    QByteArray ret;
    foreach (char c, str)
        ret.append((c + 1) % 256);
    return ret;
}

...

rhs->setText(QString::fromAscii(encrypt(str.toUtf8())));
```

**Update**:

Decrypt function:

```
QByteArray decrypt(const QByteArray &str)
{
    QByteArray ret;
    foreach (char c, str)
    {
        char r = c - 1;
        if (r < 0)
            r += 256;
        ret.append(r);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Usage:

```
rhs->setText(QString::fromAscii(decrypt(str.toUtf8())));
```

This decrypts for parameter '1' - you can easily change it for parameter '10'.

Comment: would this go outside of my function that I put of inside of my IF statement?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question right... The function goes anywhere in the same scope. the 'setText' line should replace `rhs->setText(str.toUpper());`

Comment: Sorry, I will be more clear. Do I put it at:
If (mode_combobox->currentText() == "Encrypt")
{
Then put the bytearray function. That is the part that confuses me
}

Comment: As I said, you can put `encrypt` function anywhere, as long as it stays in the same (or higher) scope, as your `void translationForm::translate()` method. If it was me, I would create new pair of 'h+cpp' files and put it there, in case you need to use it in another place.

Comment: by h+cpp files. YOu mean like a new header and new source file. right?

Comment: and finally how do I set up decrypt now. I don't understand how your function worked so I don't understand how to reverse it.

Comment: 1. Yes - new header and source files. 2. Add your old decrypter to the question and I'll convert it for you. Basically, my function works just like your's, but uses different types, cycle `for` instead of `while`, and creates new variable instead of changing the old one.

Comment: Ok I added it on. And I did make one change to your encryption code, in case that matters.   Instead of c+1 I changed it to c+10

Comment: Here is your decrypt function.

Comment: Thank you. And when I put it in .deb package form I will make sure to Put you in the contribution part of the READ-ME file.